# Python: Sending a dictionary's items to a list of lists

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

I've got a dictionary like:

```
Dd = {'a':99, 'aa': 109, 'abc':199, 'aabb':100.99, 'abcabc':99.109}
```

I want to make a list of each Key, Value pair then append each list to one main list. I mean something like this:

```
Ll = [['a', 99], ['aa', 109], ['abc', 199], ['aabb', 100.99], ['abcabc', 99.109]]
```

I wrote this piece of code:

```
L = Ll = []
for (Chr, Num) in Dd.items ():
    L.append (Chr)
    L.append (Num)
    Ll.append (L)
    L = [] #Flushing this variable to be refilled in next loop
```

But `Ll`'s output was not what I expected:

```
print (Ll)

['aabb', 100.99, [...], ['abcabc', 99.109], ['a', 99], ['abc', 199], ['aa', 109]]
```

Why did it become like that?! How can I produce my desired list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the dictionary Dd. You want to prepare a list of lists with key and value pair we can make use of comprehensions.

Here is the one line solution:

```
[ [x,y] for x in Dd.keys() for y in Dd.values() if Dd[x] == y ]
```

Or even better:

```
[[x, y] for x, y in Dd.items()]
```

Comment: Your original post (and the still present first example) turned a `O(n)` problem into a `O(n**2)` problem, iterating `values` once for every key for no reason. That's *terrible* code. Even if you didn't know about `.items()`, you could have done this without algorithmic wastefulness with just `[[k, Dd[k]] for k in Dd]`.

Comment: Quite agree, thanks for commenting, helps me improve my quality of answer. Hence I have edited my answer quickly

Comment: @ShadowRanger That was a goddamn super minimalistic thing!

Answer (score 2):

Here, you problem is contained in the first line. By writing `L = Ll = []`, both L and Ll references the same list.

With the following declaration:

```
L, Ll = [], []
```

It would work better (`L` and `Ll` are initialized with two different lists).
Morover, You could use list comprehension as pointed out by Romaan.

Moreover, If you want the list to be in this specific order, you need to rethink the usage of a dict, where key order is not defined. See `collections.OrderedDict` if key order is important to you.

Comment: for the first part of your answer I received the very same wrong list. I'll go study more about what you said about OrderedDict. Thanks.

Comment: @MerlotLatterian I'm really surprised by your statement. Don't you forget to remove `L = Ll = []` somewhere? In my case, the list output looks OK (excepting an ordering issue)

Comment: I exactly tried other different names in case that those one are still in my cache. I wrote `Lll, Llll = [], []` And again the wrong list with this stupid item `[...]` again!

Comment: @MerlotLatterian really really surprised: check this out: http://ideone.com/bUScj9

Comment: This is really weird! I'm confused now!

Comment: By the way, thanks for introducing IDEONE to me. I was looking for such a thing. That was a help too! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, `.items()` gets you a `list` of `tuple`s. It's not hard to convert that to a `list` of `list`s:

```
Ll = list(map(list, Dd.items()))
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
Ll = [[k, v] for k, v in Dd.items()]
```

Your actual problem is that `L` and `Ll` are references to the same `list`. `x = y = z` means `x`, `y` and `z` are all referencing the same thing; if that thing is mutable, mutations, excluding reassignment, of one changes all of them). Your code replaces `L` with a new fresh `list` after the first loop, but in the first loop, each `append` is appending to both the sublist and the parent (because they're the same thing). For `list`s, you'd want `L, Ll = [], []`, although frankly, `L` isn't needed since for a fixed two items, you could just assign `L = [Chr, Num]` on each loop (or directly `append` the same `list` literal).

Comment: In python3 it would be just item( ) @ShadowRanger

Comment: @ShadowRanger Python3 is my case. I've never worked with Python2

Comment: Well done mentioning `map` (I love map). In Python 3, `map` would then need to be wrapped in a `list` call, since it returns an iterator, not a list like it did in Python 2.

Comment: @eestrada: I could have sworn the question was originally tagged for Python 2.7, and answered accordingly. It's now tagged for 3.x, so I've fixed it for Py3.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Well I'm pretty sure I tagged it for Python3 and you can see I ain't made and edition yet. By the way, your minimalistic correction on Romaan's reply did work.

Comment: @MerlotLatterian: Yeah, probably a brain fart on my part. That said, using `.items` is better than the version I posted that does `[k, Dd[k]]` primarily because the extra lookup is usually more expensive than getting both key and value at once, "for free" by iterating `.items()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your issue is order of items. Use `import collections` and then create OrderedDict and use list comprehension to get items of this ordered dictionary to create list.

Comment: I studied about OrderedDict. Thanks but if you look at my output, my case is not about ordering. It's about wrong items.